# Casting type of columns in a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My Spark program needs to read a file which contains a matrix of integers. Columns are separated with ",". Number of columns is not the same each time I run the program.

I read the file as a dataframe:

`var df = spark.read.csv(originalPath);`

but when I print schema it gives me all the columns as Strings.

I convert all columns to Integers as below but after that when I print the schema of df again, columns are still Strings.

```
df.columns.foreach(x => df.withColumn(x + "_new", df.col(x).cast(IntegerType))
.drop(x).withColumnRenamed(x + "_new", x));
```

I appreciate any help to solve the issue of casting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DataFrames` are immutable. Your code creates new `DataFrame` for each value and discards it.

It is best to use `map` and `select`:

```
val newDF = df.select(df.columns.map(c => df.col(c).cast("integer")): _*)
```

but you could `foldLeft`:

```
df.columns.foldLeft(df)((df, x) => df.withColumn(x , df.col(x).cast("integer")))
```

or even (**please don't**) mutable reference:

```
var df = Seq(("1", "2", "3")).toDF

df.columns.foreach(x => df = df.withColumn(x , df.col(x).cast("integer")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or as you mentioned your column numbers are not same each time, you could take the highest number of possible column and make a schema out of it, having **IntegerType** as column type. During loading the file infer this schema to automatically convert your dataframe columns from string to integer. No explicit conversion required in this case.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val csvSchema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("_c0", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("_c1", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("_c2", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("_c3", IntegerType, true)))

val df = spark.read.schema(csvSchema).csv(originalPath)

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- _c0: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- _c1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- _c2: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- _c3: integer (nullable = true)
```